Idk how to put a open interval on graph on the overleaf
I've been struggling with the graph f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-2), I know that is equal to f(x)=x+2, but it's undefined when x=2, where there should be an open interval. I am unsure how to place the open interval indication at the x=2 location. My attempt to make the code is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle, 
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(y\)},
]


\addplot [
    domain=-5:5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{x+2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I am seeking help to learn how this is done.

The axis environment is from pgfplots.  Also, you were missing a semicolon.
IIRC, open points are marked with circles.  I used standalone class to avoid cropping the image.
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle, xlabel = (x), ylabel = {(y)}, ]
\addplot [ domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red, ] {x+2};% samples=2 would do
\path (axis cs: 2,4) node[circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, fill=white] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


